# Using object in Crystal Reports: Error in formula if object is null or nothing

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I am using crystal reports with vb.net
I have an API which sends me an object with some fields in it. I have the same fields declared in a datatable with same name and datatypes as in the original object.

Now I have a formula in CR which checks for a field value and displays a text accordingly. Eg: if{objectname.fieldname}=1 then "showthistext" else "showanothertext"

The field is of  type integer.
Now this works if the object has some values. But if the object has no records in it, the CR shows error in formula saying "A String is expected here"
Any ideas on how to fix this.
I cannot modify this in the API as the object cannot be changed from integer to string and back.

Answer (score 1):

I just found that using an integer for comparision in formulas is cuasing issues when the object is null.
So I used Cstr on both sides on "=" in the formula if the field of comparision in not a string.

***if isnull({objectname.fieldname}) then ""
else (
if cstr({objectname.fieldname})= cstr(1) then "show one"
else if cstr({objectname.fieldname}) = cstr(2) then "show two"***

I don't know if this is the best, but it solved the issue for me.
Thanks to the user "Siva" for the help. The response gave some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

First check is null condition then write your formula... it is encountering null hwnce programme is getting terminated.

If IsNull({objectname.fieldname}
Then "showsometext"
Else
(
if{objectname.fieldname}=1 then "showthistext" else "showanothertext"
)

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tried it, I get : "A String is expected here" excpetion. The field I'm trying to use in the formula is of type Int16. Does that cause a problem?

Comment: Are you showing result of a formula as int or string

Comment: A string .  My formula says:  if isnull({objectname.fieldname}) then " " else (if {objectname.fieldname} = 1 then "showone" else "showtwo"). This works fine when there is data. But when object is null I get an error saying 'if isnull({objectname.fieldname}) then " " ' A String is expected here.

Comment: It also works as expected if I use the formula if isnull({objectname.fieldname}) then "" else "showone" The problem starts when I use {objectname.fieldname} for comparision after the null check and the object is null. I could not figure what causes it to fail that particular combination when the object is null